# Why does AWS S3 JavaScript Example Code save objects into a nameless subfolder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried posting the following question on the AWS forum but I got the error message - "Your account is not ready for posting messages yet.", which is why I'm posting this here.

I am reading through the following example code for Amazon S3:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album-full.html

Whenever a new object is created, the example code nests the object within a nameless sub-folder like so:

```
function addPhoto(albumName) {
  var files = document.getElementById('photoupload').files;
  if (!files.length) {
    return alert('Please choose a file to upload first.');
  }
  var file = files[0];
  var fileName = file.name;
  // Why is the photo placed in a nameless subfolder (below)?
  var albumPhotosKey = encodeURIComponent(albumName) + '//';
  ...
```

**Is there a particular reason / need for this?**

Comment: If there is a reason, it is not an obvious one.